# Spring Boot authentication for different types of User

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot. I want to create a school management system where teachers and students can log in. After sign in Page, I am sending jwt token. I want to know what should be the approach followed here for authentication. There are api that should be strictly accessed by teacher and by students. I was seeing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but not sure who to handle two different sets of Users?

Comment: did you check [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure-org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder-)? The `configure` method allows you to define user roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you need to use Spring Security. First of all you need to create two roles `TEACHER` and `STUDENT`. Then based on your requirements you will give an access for controller`s methods inside `configure` function. **configure** function  should be inside SecurityConfig.java. And also `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation should be on top of the class. If you read username and password from database then inside `configAuthentication` function you will check.

**For example**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("STUDENT","TEACHER")
        .antMatchers("/add_friends").hasAnyRole( "TEACHER")
        .antMatchers("/showAllData").hasAnyRole( "TEACHER")
        .antMatchers("/show_users").hasAnyRole( "TEACHER")
        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .successForwardUrl("/welcome_page")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

```
@Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from core_users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from core_authorities where username=?");
    }
```

Comment: I am building rest API, I believe this one might be including JSP ?

Comment: Rest API is also almost the same. Do you want to check username and password from database or static username and password?

Comment: @Rohit Yes I used JSP. If you use InMemoryUserDetails then create ```UserDetailsService``` bean inside ```SecurityConfig``` class.

Comment: I recommend you to watch Spring Security Course [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=her_7pa0vrg&t=9131s). This gives you thorough idea of Spring Security.